# package-initialize: wrong type argument : arrayp , nil

Tags: package, start-up

while going through the [emacs as a c/c++ editor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTUE03LnaXA) , I came across the following lines of code to include in my `~/.emacs` file, to connect to 
`melpa archives` for package installation

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

after saving these lines into emacs , when i started emacs it is showing me an `wrong type argument: arrayp, nil` in the minibuffer area

when i tried for `$ emacs --debug -init` , I got :

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument arrayp nil)
  package--add-to-archive-contents(nil "melpa")
  package-read-archive-contents("melpa")
  package-read-all-archive-contents()
  package-initialize()
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/anupam/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 905
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/anupam/.emacs" "/home/anupam/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262�    \306=\203�\307\310Q\202;�   \311=\204�\307\312Q\202;�\313\307\314\315#\203*�\316\202;�\313\307\314\317#\203:�\320\nB\321\202;�\316\322\323\322\211#\210\322=\203a�\324\325\326\307\327Q!\"\323\322\211#\210\322=\203`�\210\203\243�\330!\331\232\203\243�\332!\211\333P\334!\203}�\211\202\210�\334!\203\207�\202\210�\314\262\203\241�\335\"\203\237�\336\337#\210\340\341!\210\266\f?\205\260�\314\323\342\322\211#)\262\207" [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs" windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" (initialization "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'") "~/_emacs" t load expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7 "\n\n(fn)"]()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

I am new to emacs, can someone please tell me how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I ran into this the other day. I think it was caused by an invalid package archive file. The immediate fix is to delete `<user-emacs-directory>/elpa/archives/melpa/archive-contents`; it will be rebuilt on the next `package-initialize`. Unfortunately, package.el is not very robust to this sort of failure.

Comment: you are right it worked for me about 12 hours, then suddenly this problem came out of nowhere.. besides many packages  mentioned in the tutorial series are not in the standard elpa.gnu.org..

Comment: isn't there any other alternative to solve this problem?

Comment: I think it's probably a bug in MELPA (combined with a lack of resilience in package.el), you might want to file an issue there.

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, but the address for the repository has change: now it recommends: `(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))`

Comment: I ran in the same problem after a package upgrade. The fix worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: This answer also works for the error `package-read-archive-contents: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and applied the following fix. This worked for me:

- Change the address for the melpa archive to: "http://melpa.org/packages"
- Delete the ~/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/melpa/archive-contents file
- Run package-initialize and package-refresh-contents.

I have a package-refresh-contents command in my .emacs file. This ensures that the packages are always up to date but it adds about two seconds to the boot time of emacs.

My package-related commands in .emacs look like this:

```
;; Package system
(require 'package)
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
                         ("user42" . "http://download.tuxfamily.org/user42/elpa/packages/")))
(package-initialize)

(package-refresh-contents)
(setq auto-install-packages
      '(color-theme bar-cursor htmlize flycheck flycheck-haskell
                    haskell-mode sml-mode rust-mode fsharp-mode nasm-mode go-mode
                    perl-mode web-mode )) ;;ffap-perl-module markdown-mode))
(dolist (pkg auto-install-packages)
  (unless (package-installed-p pkg)
    (package-install pkg)))
```

Comment: I am experiencing this problem quite often. I wonder if there is a way to automate the deleting of the file ~/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/melpa/archive-contents whenever this problem occurs.

Comment: Do you mean `alias rm_archive='rm -r <user-emacs-directory>/elpa/archives/melpa/archive-contents'` in your `~/.bashrc` file?